# Get absolute path for the file where the function has been called

Tags: python, path

I wanted to make a util function that returns the absolute path for the file, where the function has been called, however I did not found a way to do so.

For a better picture, this is what I'm trying to achieve.

Suppose I have the following directory structure:

```
core/
    utils/
        __init__.py
        files.py
    __init__.py
    service.py
```

where `files.py` contains

```
import os

def get_current_dir():
    return os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

and `service.py` contains

```
from utils.files import get_current_dir


print(get_current_dir())
```

The expected results are not the desired ones.

What I wanted to achieve: `/usr/src/app/core` 
The actual output: `/usr/src/app/core/utils`

I've been looking for on many answers here, but none of them has an example where a function is used to determine the path.

Are there any ways or is it at least possible to achieve what I'm looking for?

Thanks!

Comment: The term "current directory" is used for a different concept. You should use a better name.

Comment: Have a look at [**`inspect`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#the-interpreter-stack)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply pass `__file__` as a parameter
in files.py

```
import os

def get_current_dir(file):
    return os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(file))
```

in service.py

```
from utils.files import get_current_dir


print(get_current_dir(__file__))
```

Comment: hah, I was thinking in more complex terms. Thank you, this did the trick!